# javac cannot find symbol errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

In my code I use Junit and a package given to me.
like this:

```
import java.awt.Image;

import oop.ex3.*;
```

when i use the command:

> javac *.java

in the directory I get a lot of

> cannot find symbol

errors and it does not find the package:

> error: package oop.ex3 does not exist
>   import oop.ex3.*;

Help anyone?

thanks!

Comment: Have you added those jar in the classpath?

Comment: the jar is in the main directory **and** in oop/ex3 directory.

Comment: What is your class path looks like ?

Comment: what do you mean by classpath?

Comment: Just search, **What's classpath in java and How to add jar file to class path?**